# PIC18F8722 serial comms with 4D Systems uLCD-70-DT

Tags: microchip, usart

I'm working on a Project that uses the 4D Systems gen4 uLCD-70dt and a PIC18F8722to control a machine.  The two devices are linked using a pair of MAX232 serial drivers.

I had previously breadboarded this setup using a PIC18F4520 and had no problems with serial communications.  Now when the PIC sends a poll request to the display, the display responds, however the data is not received by the PIC. 
The code id very simple (for testing)and I have checked the data stream, both RX abd TX, at the PIC pins using a scope and the signal looks fine. (voltages and baud rate check out)

I did use a GenieSerial.h that was built for the 18F4520 I found online and adapted it for the 18f8722. (the error is likely here)

I'm guessing I have an error in my configuration bits or the EUSART setup bits but cant for the life of me find it.

Any help is apreciated

Main code:

```
   /*
   * File:   trial1.c
   * Author: Steve
   *
   * Created on May 2, 2017, 3:06 PM
   */

// PIC18F8722 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config OSC = HS         // Oscillator Selection bits (External RC       oscillator, CLKO function on RA6)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Two-Speed Start-up disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = OFF       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = SBORDIS  // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset enabled in hardware only (SBOREN is disabled))
#pragma config BORV = 3         // Brown-out Voltage bits (Minimum setting)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = OFF        // Watchdog Timer (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768    // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

// CONFIG3L
#pragma config MODE = MC        // Processor Data Memory Mode Select bits (Microcontroller mode)
#pragma config ADDRBW = ADDR20BIT// Address Bus Width Select bits (20-bit Address Bus)
#pragma config DATABW = DATA16BIT// Data Bus Width Select bit (16-bit External Bus mode)
#pragma config WAIT = OFF       // External Bus Data Wait Enable bit (Wait selections are unavailable for table reads and table writes)

 // CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MX = PORTC   // CCP2 MUX bit (ECCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RC1)
#pragma config ECCPMX = PORTE   // ECCP MUX bit (ECCP1/3 (P1B/P1C/P3B/P3C) are multiplexed onto RE6, RE5, RE4 and RE3 respectively)
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF    // Low-Power Timer1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR pin enabled; RG5 input pin disabled)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP enabled)
#pragma config BBSIZ = BB2K     // Boot Block Size Select bits (1K word (2 Kbytes) Boot Block size)
#pragma config XINST = OFF      // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit Block 0 (Block 0 (000800, 001000 or 002000-003FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit Block 1 (Block 1 (004000-007FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        // Code Protection bit Block 2 (Block 2 (008000-00BFFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF        // Code Protection bit Block 3 (Block 3 (00C000-00FFFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP4 = OFF        // Code Protection bit Block 4 (Block 4 (010000-013FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP5 = OFF        // Code Protection bit Block 5 (Block 5 (014000-017FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP6 = OFF        // Code Protection bit Block 6 (Block 6 (01BFFF-018000h) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP7 = OFF        // Code Protection bit Block 7 (Block 7 (01C000-01FFFFh) not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-0007FFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit Block 0 (Block 0 (000800, 001000 or 002000-003FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit Block 1 (Block 1 (004000-007FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection bit Block 2 (Block 2 (008000-00BFFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection bit Block 3 (Block 3 (00C000-00FFFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT4 = OFF       // Write Protection bit Block 4 (Block 4 (010000-013FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT5 = OFF       // Write Protection bit Block 5 (Block 5 (014000-017FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT6 = OFF       // Write Protection bit Block 6 (Block 6 (01BFFF-018000h) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT7 = OFF       // Write Protection bit Block 7 (Block 7 (01C000-01FFFFh) not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-007FFF, 000FFF or 001FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit Block 0 (Block 0 (000800, 001000 or 002000-003FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit Block 1 (Block 1 (004000-007FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit Block 2 (Block 2 (008000-00BFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit Block 3 (Block 3 (00C000-00FFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR4 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit Block 4 (Block 4 (010000-013FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR5 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit Block 5 (Block 5 (014000-017FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR6 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit Block 6 (Block 6 (018000-01BFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR7 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit Block 7 (Block 7 (01C000-01FFFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-007FFF, 000FFF or 001FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
#include "GenieSerial.h"
#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000


// MAIN PROGRAM LOOP

void main()
{
    unsigned char incoming=37;

    usart();

    while(1)
    {


        incoming = genieread(0x04,0x00);        //read slider 0
        __delay_ms(104);
        geniewrite_coolgauge(0x00, incoming);    //send data back to display here
         __delay_ms(104);

    }
}`
```

and the GenieSerial.h:

```
#define READ                    0x00
#define WRITE                   0x01


//objects

#define DIPSWITCH               0x00
#define KNOB                    0x01
#define ROCKERSW                0x02
#define ROTARYSW                0x03
#define SLIDER                  0x04
#define TRACKBAR                0x05
#define BUTTON                  0x06
#define ANGULAR_METER           0x07
#define COOL_GAUGE              0x08
#define CUSTOM_DIGITS           0x09
#define FORM                    0x0A
#define GAUGE                   0x0B
#define IMAGE                   0X0C
#define KEYBOARD                0X0D
#define LED                     0X0E
#define LED_DIGITS              0X0F
#define METER                   0X10
#define STRINGS                 0X11
#define THERMOMETER             0X12
#define USER_LED                0X13
#define VIDEO                   0X14
#define STATIC_TEXT             0X15
#define SOUND                   0X16
#define TIMER                   0X17
#define CONTRAST                0x04
#define PLAY                    0X00
#define STOP                    0x04
#define ON                      0X01
#define OFF                     0x00
#define VIDEOPLAY               0X01
#define VIDEOSTOP               0X00

void usart(void)
{
    INTCONbits.GIE=1;   //enable global interrupts
    INTCONbits.PEIE=1;  //enable peripheral interrupts
    TRISCbits.TRISC7=1; //Make UART RX pin input
    TRISCbits.TRISC6=0; //Make UART TX pin output
    SPBRGH  = 0x00    ;     //9600bps 20MHz Osc
    SPBRG   = 31;

    RCSTA1bits.CREN=1;   //1 = Enables receiver
    RCSTA1bits.SPEN=1;   //1 = Serial port enabled (configures RX/DT and TX/CK pins as serial port pins)
    BAUDCON1bits.BRG16=0;//0 = 8-bit Baud Rate Generator ? SPBRGH and SPBRG
    BAUDCON1bits.ABDEN=0;

    TXSTA1bits.SYNC=0;  //0 = Asynchronous mode
    TXSTA1bits.BRGH=0;  //0 = low speed
    TXSTA1bits.SENDB = 0;
    BAUDCON1bits.WUE =0;
    PIE1bits.TXIE = 1;
    PIE1bits.RC1IE =1;

}

    ///////////////////////////////////////////

unsigned char receive(void)
{
    unsigned char data;
    if(RCSTAbits.FERR==1 && RCSTAbits.OERR==1 )
    {
        while(PIR1bits.RCIF == 1)
        {
          RCSTAbits.CREN =0;    //Overrun error (can be cleared by clearing bit CREN)
          data = RCREG;
          RCSTAbits.CREN =1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
       while(PIR1bits.RCIF == 1)
        {
            RCSTAbits.CREN =0;    //Overrun error (can be cleared by clearing bit CREN)
            data = RCREG;
            RCSTAbits.CREN =1;
        }
    }
    return data;
}

void send(void)
{
    TXSTAbits.TXEN=0;
        while(TXSTAbits.TRMT == 0)
        {
                TXSTAbits.TXEN=1;    // enable transmission
                while(TXSTAbits.TRMT == 0 ) // wait here till transmit complete
                {
                }
        }
    TXSTAbits.TXEN=0;
}

   ///////////////////////////////////////////////

void sendbyte(unsigned char data)
{
    TXREG = data;
    TXSTAbits.TXEN=0;
        while(TXSTAbits.TRMT == 0)
        {
                TXSTAbits.TXEN=1;    // enable transmission
                while(TXSTAbits.TRMT == 0 ) // wait here till transmit complete
                {
                }
        }
    TXSTAbits.TXEN=0;
}



void sendarray(unsigned char value, unsigned char value2, unsigned char value3,unsigned char value4,unsigned int value5)
{
       TXREG = value;
       send();
       TXREG = value2;
       send();
       TXREG = value3;
       send();
       TXREG = value4;
       send();
       TXREG = value5;
       send();
       TXREG = (value ^ value2 ^ value3 ^ value4 ^ value5);
       send();
}

void geniewrite_coolgauge(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)                 // write cool gauge object with a value of 0-255
{
       TXREG = WRITE;       send();
       TXREG = COOL_GAUGE;  send();
       TXREG = index;       send();
       TXREG = 0x00;        send();
       TXREG = value;       send();
       TXREG = (WRITE ^ COOL_GAUGE ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value); send();
}
void geniewrite_gauge(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
       TXREG = WRITE;       send();
       TXREG = GAUGE;       send();
       TXREG = index;       send();
       TXREG = 0x00;        send();
       TXREG = value;       send();
       TXREG = (WRITE ^ GAUGE ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);      send();
}
void geniewrite_slider(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
       TXREG = WRITE;       send();
       TXREG = SLIDER;      send();
       TXREG = index;       send();
       TXREG = 0x00;        send();
       TXREG = value;       send();
       TXREG = (WRITE ^ SLIDER ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);     send();
}
void geniewrite_meter(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
       TXREG = WRITE;       send();
       TXREG = METER;       send();
       TXREG = index;       send();
       TXREG = 0x00;        send();
       TXREG = value;       send();
       TXREG = (WRITE ^ METER ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);      send();
}
void geniewrite_winbutton(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
       TXREG = WRITE;       send();
       TXREG = BUTTON;      send();
       TXREG = index;       send();
       TXREG = 0x00;        send();
       TXREG = value;       send();
       TXREG = (WRITE ^ BUTTON ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);     send();
}

void geniewrite_dipswitch(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
       TXREG = WRITE;       send();
       TXREG = DIPSWITCH;   send();
       TXREG = index;       send();
       TXREG = 0x00;        send();
       TXREG = value;       send();
       TXREG = (WRITE ^ DIPSWITCH ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);     send();
}
void geniewrite_knob(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG = KNOB;        send();
           TXREG = index;       send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = value;       send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^ KNOB ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);       send();
}
void geniewrite_rockerswitch(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG =ROCKERSW;     send();
           TXREG = index;       send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = value;       send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^ ROCKERSW ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);   send();
}
void geniewrite_rotaryswitch(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
 {
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG = ROTARYSW;    send();
           TXREG = index;       send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = value;       send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^ ROTARYSW ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);       send();
}
void geniewrite_trackbar(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG = TRACKBAR;        send();
           TXREG = index;       send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = value;       send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^ TRACKBAR ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);       send();
}
void geniewrite_keyboard(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG = KEYBOARD;    send();
           TXREG = index;       send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = value;       send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^ KEYBOARD ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);       send();
}
void geniewrite_angularmeter(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;           send();
           TXREG = ANGULAR_METER;   send();
           TXREG = index;           send();
           TXREG = 0x00;            send();
           TXREG = value;           send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^ ANGULAR_METER ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);       send();
}
void geniewrite_thermometer(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG = THERMOMETER; send();
           TXREG = index;       send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = value;       send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^ THERMOMETER ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);       send();
}
void geniewrite_LED(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG = LED;         send();
           TXREG = index;       send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = value;       send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^ LED ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);       send();
}
void geniewrite_userLED(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG = USER_LED;    send();
           TXREG = index;       send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = value;       send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^ USER_LED ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);       send();
}
void geniewrite_LEDdigits(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG = LED_DIGITS;  send();
           TXREG = index;       send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = value;       send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^ LED_DIGITS ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);       send();
}
void geniewrite_customdigits(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG = CUSTOM_DIGITS;        send();
           TXREG = index;       send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = value;       send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^CUSTOM_DIGITS ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);       send();
}
void geniewrite_string(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG = STRINGS;     send();
           TXREG = index;       send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = value;       send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^ STRINGS ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);       send();
}
void geniewrite_form(unsigned char index)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG = FORM;        send();
           TXREG = index;       send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^ FORM ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ 0x00);       send();
}
void geniewrite_videoGIF(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG = VIDEO;       send();
           TXREG = index;       send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = value;       send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^ VIDEO ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);       send();
}
void geniewrite_timer(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG = TIMER;       send();
           TXREG = index;       send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = value;       send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^TIMER  ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);       send();
}
void geniewrite_sound(unsigned char index, unsigned char value)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG = SOUND;       send();
           TXREG = index;       send();
           TXREG = 0x00;        send();
           TXREG = value;       send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^ TIMER  ^ index ^ 0x00 ^ value);       send();
}
void geniewrite(unsigned char value, unsigned char value2)
{
           TXREG = WRITE;       send();
           TXREG = value;       send();
           TXREG = value2;      send();
           TXREG = (WRITE ^ CONTRAST ^ value);       send();
}

unsigned char genieread(unsigned char object, unsigned char index)
{
    unsigned char data, data1, data2, data3, data4, data5;    
    TXREG = READ;               send();
    TXREG = object;             send();
    TXREG = index;              send();
    TXREG = (READ ^ object ^ index); send();

    data = receive();
    data1 = receive();
    data2 = receive();
    data3 = receive();
    data4 = receive();
    data5 = receive();
    return data4;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you connect the serial port of the pic to a rs232 to usb adapter? Does the terminal client show the expected data? And when you send the pic data, does it receive it?

Answer (score 0):

The GenieSerial.h enables both send and receive interrupts while there's no interrupt handler. This may cause problems if the interrupt flags aren't reset properly. I'd disable the interrupts first and see if that clears it up:

```
PIE1bits.TXIE  = 0;
PIE1bits.RC1IE = 0;
```

Since it's only using polling to handle the serial port, it's better to disable the interrupts.

Also make sure that the oscillator runs at the expected frequency. According to the datasheet the serial port runs at 9766 baud. Make sure this doesn't cause any problems. You can use the alternative setting for 20MHz with BRGH = 1 and SPBRG = 129 which sets the speed to 9615 baud, which is closer to the 9600 baud spec. See page 253 in the datasheet (39646c.pdf).